# Why does my array appear empty when calling a function after the array is built in JS

Tags: javascript

```
// variables to be used throughout
var videos = new Array();

// similar artist/bands
function similarTo(who) {
    $.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist='+who+'&limit=20&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json&callback=?', function(data) {
        $.each(data , function(i,similars) {
            $.each(similars.artist, function(c, artist) {
                $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+artist.name+'&orderby=relevance&start-index=1&max-results=1&v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?', function(data) {
                    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,video) {
                        videos.push({ 
                            id: video.id.$t.split(":")[3], 
                            title: video.title.$t 
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            initPlaylist();
        });
    });
}

// start the playlist
function initPlaylist() {
    $('#ytplayerid').load('includes/ytplayer.php?track=' + videos[currenttrack].id);
    $('#player span').html(videos[currenttrack].title);
}
```

When my code reaches the `initPlaylist()` function the videos array appears to be empty, I have a feeling its actually being fired before the `$.getJSON()` call... is this possible? If I add a *console.log*(videos) after each `push()` the array is actually being built.

Comment: I think this is a scope issues.  Where is `videos` being defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(similars.artist, function(c, artist) {
    // doing ajax stuff here
    $.getJSON('url', function(data) {
        // this will get called later
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,video) {
            videos.push({ 
                id: video.id.$t.split(":")[3], 
                title: video.title.$t 
            });
        });
    });
});
// trying to manipulate ajax data now :(
initPlaylist();
```

Your `videos` is empty because your trying to manipulate it before it's ready.

What you want to do is use jQuery 1.5+ deferred objects

```
var ajaxs = $.map(similars.artist, function(artist, c) {
    return $.getJSON('url', function(data) {
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,video) {
            videos.push({ 
                id: video.id.$t.split(":")[3], 
                title: video.title.$t 
            });
        });
    });
});
// when all the ajaxs finish then call init play list
$.when.apply($, ajaxs).then(initPlaylist);
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for your response, it did the trick... now I just need to go back and learn why and how the above works :)

Answer (score 1):

Move `initPlaylist` to a point where `videos` exists:

```
function similarTo(who) {
$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist='+who+'&limit=20&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json&callback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data , function(i,similars) {
        $.each(similars.artist, function(c, artist) {
            $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+artist.name+'&orderby=relevance&start-index=1&max-results=1&v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?', function(data) {
                var videoes = [];  //create array
                $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,video) {
                    videos.push({ 
                        id: video.id.$t.split(":")[3], 
                        title: video.title.$t 
                    });
                });
                initPlaylist(); 
            //videos exists, but i think you might need to pass it as a parameter
            });
        });
    });

});
}
```

Although, knowing what is in `initPlaylist();` might help. And it might solve what appears to be a scope problem in your code.

ALSO: Ajax is asynchronous, there forit might not finish by the time the code gets to `initPlaylist();`, so you need some type of callback to call `initPlaylist();` when all the ajax calls are done.

Comment: That causes initPlaylist to be called every time a video is added to the videos array. It only needs to happen once, and thats when the array is done building. Oh, and the videos array is declared outside the function.

Comment: @Cody.Stewart, you have a scope problem. what is the `initPlaylist();` function?

Comment: more elbow grease. Explain the whole ajax is asynchronous.